# Property page of Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I open the property page of a project in Visual Studio 2015 I have only Configuration Properties -> Code Analysis -> General.

[image]

Why I do not have debuging, linking editor, ... ?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Comment: What is the extension of the project you are viewing the properties of (e.g. *.csproj)?

Comment: It is a .vcxproj. Yesterday, I did not have any problem. This morning, I installed the extension visualHg. I do not know if it is linked. But now this problem is the same for all my project.  I think the problem is linked to the visual's settings and not to the project.

Comment: Does this happen both if you open the panel from the toolbar and also if you right click on the project in the solution explorer and choose properties?

Comment: Yes, the behaviour is the same.

Comment: [Property pages of Visual Studio 2015 seem to leave out a lot of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621418/property-pages-of-visual-studio-2015-seem-to-leave-out-a-lot-of-items) shows the same problem. The problem is due to language settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is resolved. I uninstalled completely and installed again Visual 2015.