# Property pages of Visual Studio 2015 seem to leave out a lot of items

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

The following snapshot is is the project property pages.
[image]

I don’t know why the property pages leave out a lot of items by comparison with the following snapshot coming from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx. 
[image]

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, Version 14.0.23107.0 D 14REL, on Windows 10 Enterprise, and I'm working on C++ project.

Comment: "leave out a lot of items" like what items? These looks like fine properly pages. Maybe you were looking for `Project properties`?

Comment: I'm sorry, @VTT, I have edited my question. The property pages were OK a few days ago. I don’t know what I have done to cause this problem.

Comment: The second project is probably a non-C++ project and thus doesn't display such options. There's really not enough information for us to go on ( such as reproduction steps) - the best anyone can suggest you do is try upgrading to a supported VS version, such as VS15.

Comment: It's really a C++ project. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I find the cause of the problem from [Missing Properties when opening VS2010 C++ projects with VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023199/missing-properties-when-opening-vs2010-c-projects-with-vs2015?noredirect=1&lq=1). It’s hard to believe that the problem is due to language settings.

In Visual Studio 2015 Chinese version, project property pages are OK.
[image]